# Google Maps V3 infowindow content with alert

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

First what I want in this project is a small pedipaper. People carry the first button and if you have to go right to the point 2.
So I need a form in Google Maps that makes the response validation but I'm not succeeding.
The google is not the answer to validate me and makes me refresh when I click the submit.
Someone help me?

```
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(41.29283404, -7.74586022), // Position marker to coordinates
            icon:image, //use our image as the marker
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map, // assign the marker to our map variable
            title: '1- Museu da Vila Velha' // Marker ALT Text
        });

        // se clicar no icon vai para o link mencionado embaixo
        //  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { // Add a Click Listener to our marker 
        //      window.location='http://www.snowdonrailway.co.uk/shop_and_cafe.php'; // URL to Link Marker to (i.e Google Places Listing)
        //  });


        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ // Create a new InfoWindow
            content:"<h3>1- Museu de Vila Real</h3>"+
            "O jogo começa neste ponto até vocês não conseguirem achar a resposta não conseguem ir para o segundo ponto<br/>"+
            "<img src='http://www.cm-vilareal.pt/mvv/images/noticias/mvv_para_site.jpg' style='width:30%; margin-top: 10px; float: left;' />"+
            "<div style='padding: 15px; float: left; '>"+
            "<h4>Em que ano foi construido o museu?</h4>"+
            '<form name="form1" onsubmit="return resposta1()" method="post" >'+
            "<input type='text' name='resposta_1' />"+
            "<input type='submit' value='Validar Resposta' />"+
            '</form>'+
            "</div>" // HTML contents of the InfoWindow
        });    






            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(resposta1) {// Add a Click Listener to our marker
                infowindow.open(map,marker); // Open our InfoWindow
                infowindow.setContent(content);
            });

            function resposta1() {
                var x=document.forms['form1']['resposta_1'].value;
                if (x != '2002') {
                    alert("merda");
                    return false;   
                }
            }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you just need to prevent form submit. Try to update your reposta1 function

```
function resposta1() {

    event.preventDefault();

    var x=document.forms['form1']['resposta_1'].value;
    if (x != '2002') {
        alert("merda");
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Asgu :)

could solve the problems but thanks anyway;)
here is the resolution for anyone.

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', resposta1);

        function resposta1() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                document.forms["form1"].onsubmit = function(){
                    var x=document.forms['form1']['resposta_1'].value;
                    if (x != '2002') {
                        alert("A sua resposta está errada");
                        return false;   
                    } else {
                        alert("Parabéns, a sua respsota está certa");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
        }
```